# How would I go about declaring variables in a C# flowchart?

Tags: c#, variables, declare, flowchart

According to my programming instructor, my flowcharts for our programs have been done pretty well. However, I've been missing points for not having declared variables in my flowcharts. I declare them in the program (obviously), but I don't understand what she means when she says it's needed for the flowchart. I've already asked for her assistance and her response to me (and the rest of the students in her online courses) was to see a tutor (who is only at the school during one of my required work days). I've also tried Googling a solution and have found plenty of flowcharts, but none that seem to have declared variables so I'm kind of at a loss. The link to my flowchart is below. If ya'll need any more background on the problem or anything, let me know! I'm almost finished with this week's logic plan and this is the only thing I have left to do!

[image: Flowchart]

Comment: put a screen shot of your flowchart instead of the link.

Comment: have a look at this ....  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Zc2bK-Otqk   it has an example

Comment: Attached an image to my question. I'm definitely going to use that video for my attempt though! Thankfully I get a resubmission to correct any errors so I'll try something like this first. Thank you so much!

Comment: in practice, flowchart aren't really used... only place I really seem them used is in embedded software.

Comment: So I've heard. I'm hoping to learn this language again from a different instructor in the future. From what I've heard she doesn't use realistic situations as examples or assignments. She strictly uses the book but doesn't do anything outside of the actual text to "teach" us anything and she'll be super picky on certain aspects of problems one week and be totally lenient with them but picky with other aspects another week. I'm so happy I'm almost done with this class, she stresses me out immensely but I'm not one to give up on something I want to understand lol.

Comment: good stuff.  C# is a great language, and there's lots and lots of resources out there to learn how to use it to do all kinds of things

Comment: Would you say it's one of the friendlier languages for beginners? Is there another language you'd recommend on top of C#? I've been debating game design for future courses but I'm pretty open. I've always loved and been interested in computers and I'm mostly taking these courses to further myself personally.

Comment: Yes, its a good language for beginners right through to highly experienced.  While there are lots of languages you can use to create games, including C#, the core of the games world is C++.  Which is not as beginner friendly.     Javascript is very useful to learn, especially in the web world and often gets used for games on the web.  This is probablly a bit off topic for Stackoverflow, feel free to email if you have any general questions want any guidance

Answer (score 1):

My teacher wanted and a flowchart with variables to. I didn't understand what he really wanted because Google pictures was very different what he said, but my result was correct and right. I hope my picture can help you a little bit.

[image]

I can't add a picture. I hope the link is correct

LG Crysis909

Comment: A bit hard to understand on my end, ours obviously use the same symbols but the setup isn't what I'm used to at all. However, I still greatly appreciate the effort to help me out so thank you!

Comment: It was written in c++ / qt creator forget the Q's at the beginning of my variables. The interesting thing is at the start, there I declare my variables like in my program. Further in it, I show what I do with my variables and where I add more because I have an for loop or something else. My flowchart is basically my sourcecode. I guess nobody will really understand it without my sourcecode. We were not allowed to do it like you did it.